# SQL step by step Left join on different columns and matching between values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables. Both Tables contain PartyName but some of them are misspelled. 
E.g  TableA has “Bryan” but same party is spelled as “Brian” in TableB.

I want to Left Join Table A with Table B with following things.

1st, try to Left join Table-B on PartyName (Exact match, basically 100% match will join first)

2nd,  then whatever are left behind try to left join them with Table-B on Amount (if name does not match try to join with matching amount) – in sample they are (Pinal, Bryan)

3rd, if name and amount does not match then match Amount with +1 or -1 difference (in above sample they are Philip($251 /$250)  and Sara ($320.36 / $321)

TABLE-A

```
+-----------+--------+
| PartyName | Amount |
+-----------+--------+
| Pinal     | 200    |
| Charles   | 150    |
| Thomas    | 600    |
| Bryan     | 450    |
| Philip    | 251    |
| Sara      | 320.36 |
+-----------+--------+
```

---

TABLE-B

```
+------------+---------+------------------+
| VPartyName | VAmount | VTransactionCode |
+------------+---------+------------------+
| Peenal     |     200 | ac92ks92lk       |
| Charles    |     150 | a1dg254agfa      |
| Thomas     |     600 | 3tfgqwae4        |
| Brian      |     450 | defg4ae5dfsd     |
| Phillip    |     250 | adg54afdfad      |
| Sarah      |     321 | dg4a5fgd44yg     |
+------------+---------+------------------+
```

---

**Need following OUTPUT**

```
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
| PartyName | Amount |  TransactionCode  |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
| Pinal     | 200    | ac92ks92lk        |
| Charles   | 150    | a1dg254agfa       |
| Thomas    | 600    | 3tfgqwae4         |
| Bryan     | 450    | defg4ae5dfsd      |
| Philip    | 251    | adg54afdfad       |
| Sara      | 320.36 | dg4a5fgd44yg      |
+-----------+--------+-------------------+
```

**EDIT :** following is the sample table, it is for explanation of duplicate issue when running both the queries suggested here by Serg and Vyron.

```
CREATE TABLE #A(PartyName varchar(100), Amount float)
insert into #A values

('A',200),  
('B',200),  
('C',200),  
('D',450),  
('E',251),  
('F',320.36)

CREATE TABLE #B(VPartyName varchar(100), VAmount float, VTransactionCode varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #B VALUES
('Peenal',200,'ac92ks92lk'),
('Charles',200,'a1dg254agfa'),
('Thomas ',600,'3tfgqwae4'),
('Brian  ',450,'defg4ae5dfsd'),
('Phillip',250,'adg54afdfad'),
('Sarah  ',321,'dg4a5fgd44yg')
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you. Have simple sample data, like TransactionCods a, b, and c, instead of defg4ae5dfsd, defg4ae5efsd and dg4a5fgd44yg.

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` in `ON`

```
select a.PartyName, a.Amount, b.VTransactionCode
from TABLEA a
left join TABLEB b on b.VPartyName = a.PartyName or b.VAmount between a.Amount - 1.0 and a.Amount + 1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you achieve what you describe

```
SELECT A.PartyName
, A.Amount
, ISNULL(ISNULL(B1.VTransactionCode, B2.VTransactionCode), B3.VTransactionCode)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B B1
    ON A.PartyName = B1.VPartyName
LEFT JOIN B B2
    ON B2.VPartyName NOT IN (
            SELECT PartyName
            FROM A
            )
        AND A.Amount = B2.VAmount
LEFT JOIN B B3
    ON B3.VPartyName NOT IN (
            SELECT PartyName
            FROM A
            )
        AND B3.VAmount NOT IN (
            SELECT Amount
            FROM A
            WHERE PartyName NOT IN (
                    SELECT VPartyName
                    FROM B
                    )
            )
        AND B3.VAmount BETWEEN A.Amount - 1.0
            AND A.Amount + 1.0
```

with a bigger set of Data than what you provide.
I may have missed one or two 'V' in front of a B table column

Comment: i tried this way, but it also returns wrong values when TableB has multiple same values.  Lets says TableA has 3 rows with value (200) and TableB has 9 rows with value (200) then it returns 27 rows in result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to validate the records so you can use `OUTER APPLY` for this, based on 3 different suggested conditions as below

```
CREATE TABLE #tableA(PartyName varchar(100), Amount float)
insert into #tableA values
('Pinal',200),  
('Charles',150),  
('Thomas',600),  
('Bryan',450),  
('Philip',251),  
('Sara',320.36)

CREATE TABLE #tableB(VPartyName varchar(100), VAmount float, VTransactionCode varchar(100))
INSERT INTO #tableB VALUES
('Peenal',200,'ac92ks92lk'),
('Charles',150,'a1dg254agfa'),
('Thomas ',600,'3tfgqwae4'),
('Brian  ',450,'defg4ae5dfsd'),
('Phillip',250,'adg54afdfad'),
('Sarah  ',321,'dg4a5fgd44yg')

select a1.*,
    coalesce(b1.VTransactionCode, b2.VTransactionCode, b3.VTransactionCode) as VTransactionCode
from #tableA a1
outer apply(select b1.VPartyName, b1.VTransactionCode 
            from #tableB b1 where b1.VPartyName = a1.PartyName) b1  -- If PartyName = VPartyName
outer apply(select b2.VPartyName, b2.VTransactionCode 
            from #tableB b2 
            where b2.VAmount = a1.Amount -- If Amount = VAmount
            and b1.VPartyName is null) b2  --Name doesn't match
outer apply(select b3.VPartyName, b3.VTransactionCode 
            from #tableB b3 
            where b3.VPartyName <> a1.PartyName --Name doesn't match
            and b3.VAmount <> a1.Amount  --Amount doesn't match
            and (b3.VAmount-a1.Amount) between -1 and 1) b3  -- Amount difference between -1 to 1
where coalesce(b1.VPartyName, b2.VPartyName, b3.VPartyName) is not null -- Restricted records based on conditions
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
    PartyName   Amount
    Pinal       200
    Charles     150
    Thomas      600
    Bryan       450
    Philip      251
    Sara        320.36
```

Comment: Output required to have column TransactionCode from tableB (matching)

Comment: It's added please check, you can add more columns in similar way if required.

Comment: I tried with my production database, but having issues. Just make once changes to TableB, set value of Charles to 200 and run same query, you will get two Pinal. Make one more changes, take Tow Charles in TableA and Two Charles in TableB (with whatever value), you will 4 records of Charles in result ( 2 * 2)